# Exclamation Mark in iMessages

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

Sometimes, after i send a message to a specific person, there is an exclamation mark inside a little black bubble down on the lower right corner by the status info.

What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry it's a lower case i inside dark little bubble. Never seen it before

Comment: Press Ctrl Shift 4 on your Macbook Pro and take a picture of it. Edit your question and include that picture.

Answer (score 2):

[image: this picture?]

Does it look something like this? http://www.iqtan.com/_/rsrc/1349108748767/ios-6/9-iphone-messages/iphone-sending-and-receiving-messages/exclamation%20mark.png

This just means that the message wasn't sent, most likely because you are in an area with bad reception or Apple's iMessaging services are temporarily overwhelmed.

If not, please post a picture so we can better identify this.